# Why do the spawned child process in node fire close event even before getting executed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, parallel-processing, child-process

I am building a tool that executes puppeteer scripts from a JSON file. The challenge here is to implement parallel processing for mimicking multiple browsers which is done by passing in the userAgent, height and width to the puppeteer instance.

However, on spawning child processes, they fire the close event with code 1 without executing even a single line in compute.js.

Answers and suggestions appreciated.

index.js file

```js
const {spawn} = require('child_process');
const browserConfig = require('../config/browser-config');

// command for reference mode : npm start ref/test login 
//var mode = process.argv[2];

var testScriptName = process.argv[2];
var testScriptPath;
var testScript;
var browserList;

if (testScriptName) {
  console.log(testScriptName, '<------test-script');
  testScriptPath = './test-scripts/' + testScriptName;
  console.log(testScriptPath, '<------path');
  testScript = require(testScriptPath);
  browserList = testScript.start.browserList;
  console.log(`browserlist --> ${browserList}`);
}

browserList.forEach(function (browser){
  console.log(`browser-> ${browser}`);
  let childProcess = spawn('node', ['./workers/compute.js', testScriptName, browserConfig[browser]]);
  childProcess.on('close', function(code){
    console.log(`Child process exited with code --> ${code}`);
  });
  childProcess.on('error', function(code){
    console.log(`Child process errord with code --> ${code}`);
  });
  childProcess.on('disconnect', function(code){
    console.log(`Child process disconnect with code --> ${code}`);
  });
  childProcess.on('message', function(message){
    console.log(`Child process message --> ${message.value}`);
  });
});
```

src/workers/compute.js file

```js
process.send({value: 'messsssssss'});

var testScriptName = process.argv[2];
var testScriptPath = './test-scripts/' + testScriptName;
var hostEnv = process.argv[3];
var puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

console.log(`Inside test script for hostEnv ----->${hostEnv}`);

var testScript = require(testScriptPath);
var screenCapture = require('./screenCapture.js');

var imageCounter = 0;


async function rollout(hostEnv) {
  const width = hostEnv.width;
  const height = hostEnv.height;

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    args: [
      `--window-size=${width},${height}`
    ],
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setUserAgent(hostEnv.userAgent);
  await page.setViewport({ width, height });

  return { browser, page };
}

async function boost(page, browser) {
  var configObj = testScript;
  var startUrl = configObj.start.open;
  await page.goto(startUrl, { "waitUntil": "networkidle0" });
  await screenCapture.captureImage(page, '../../capturedImages/' + testScriptName + '/' + imageCounter + '.png');
  imageCounter++;
  await processArray(configObj.then, page, browser);
}

async function processArray(array, page, browser) {
  for (const item of array) {
    await executeStep(item, page);
  }
  await browser.close();
}

async function executeStep(element, page) {
  if (element.inputAction === 'text') {
    await page.type(element.inputElement, element.inputValue, { delay: 50 });
  } else if (element.inputAction === 'click') {
    console.log('clicking on ', element.inputElement);
    await page.click(element.inputElement);
  }
  if (element.waitFor) {
    await page.waitForSelector(element.waitFor);
  }

  if (element.screenShotArea.length > 0) {
    var div = element.screenShotArea[0];
    await screenCapture.captureImage(page, '../../capturedImages/' + testScriptName + '/' + imageCounter + '.png', div);
    imageCounter++;
  }
  console.log('.....................')
}

var {page, browser} = rollout(testScriptPath, hostEnv);
boost(page, browser);
```

The index file spawns multiple new child_processes but all the processes close with code one and all I get is if the browserList array has 3 elements:

```
Child process exited with code --> 1
Child process exited with code --> 1
Child process exited with code --> 1
```

The outcome wanted here: The compute.js code should be executed in parallel for different browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was that my node parent process was closing post spawning the child processes, since it had nothing else to do. The closing of the parent process made the child processes to close as well without doing any of the work they were supposed to accomplish.

Above is the reason for getting these:

```js
Child process exited with code --> 1
Child process exited with code --> 1
Child process exited with code --> 1
```